# Why is the buffer size in inet_ntoa 18?

Tags: c, networking

I looked at the implementations of `inet_ntoa` like [this](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/inet/inet_ntoa.c.html) and [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/ics-mr0/libc/inet/inet_ntoa.c),

I am wondering why they both allocate a buffer of 18 characters.

If I take the maximum length IPv4 address string: `255.255.255.255` the size that I need is: 3 for each octet, 3 for dots and 1 for the null terminator.
3*4+3+1 = 16.

So why do we need those 2 extra characters?

The `inet_ntoa` implementation from the first link:

```
static __thread char buffer[18];

char *
inet_ntoa (struct in_addr in)
{
  unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) &in;
  __snprintf (buffer, sizeof (buffer), "%d.%d.%d.%d",
              bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
  return buffer;
}
```

Comment: You declare buffer as `char buffer[18]`; the Standard says that `sizeof(char)` is `1`; so, why do you have a problem that `sizeof(buffer)` is `18`?

Comment: Because the maximum bytes that we need for `inet_ntoa` to work properly is 16 bytes. Those 2 extra bytes are unused, never used, for anything.

Comment: So then why did you allocate them?

Comment: So why to declare for 2 extra bytes?

Comment: It's common practice to assign a 'wee bit more' than required - just to take care of error conditions.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker He did not write the code. OP linked to two major implementations of C standard libraries that implement `inet_ntoa` function - glibc and bionic. I see [newlib](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/sys/linux/net/inet_ntoa.c) also has 18. And [musl](https://github.com/bpowers/musl/blob/master/src/network/inet_ntoa.c) has 16! [freebsd](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/lib/libc/inet/inet_ntoa.c) has 18. I think I guess that someone long time ago had written 18 and others copied.

Comment: @Yanbir neither do the authors, but they're cargo-culting it from the author of the original mistake. Only the author of musl can count.

Comment: I agree with @AdrianMole. Many people are just yoloing buffers, because they are afraid of newlines (sometimes one byte, sometimes two and stuff) and null bytes. For example here -> https://github.com/gagern/gnulib/blob/master/lib/inet_ntop.c , (although it is different function) the buffer is allocated sensibly.

Comment: I wonder if the code was originally written before TCP/IP was ubiquitous and some other addressing schemes needed more space?   In theory, an IPv6 address might need as many as 40 bytes, I believe (8 units of 4 hex plus colon or null byte).

Comment: More links I found: [klibc](https://github.com/brainflux/klibc/blob/master/usr/klibc/inet/inet_ntoa.c) has 16, [dietlibc](https://github.com/ensc/dietlibc/blob/master/libcruft/inet_ntoa.c) has 20, [uclibc](https://github.com/hwoarang/uClibc/blob/master-metag/libc/inet/addr.c#L113) has 16.

Comment: @Jonathan - Now, you're just being clever. But 'base' issues may be the root cause.

Comment: @AdrianMole if 'base' issues were the root cause then it would have been at least 20. That 18 allows for one more char for two of the four components, doesn't make sense in any base.

Comment: An "extra 2" hints at `"\r\n"`, yet that just an observation.

Comment: Should have been `"%u.%u.%u.%u"` anyway. (but maybe `unsigned` did not exist at the moment this original code was written , __snprintf did!)

Comment: @wildplasser: Nope. `unsigned char` promotes via default promotions (always in effect for variadic arguments) to `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Thanks, but I think it's less about who can count and more about who actually implemented the functions from their specifications rather than copy-and-paste and pretending it was their own original work... ;-)

Comment: @r.. you're welcome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I take the maximum length IPv4 address string: 255.255.255.255 the
>   size that I need is: 3 for each octet, 3 for dots and 1 for the null
>   terminator. 3*4+3+1 = 16.
>
> So why do we need those 2 extra characters?

Your computation is correct.  Only sixteen bytes are needed for storing the dotted-decimal address string produced by `inet_ntoa()`, including its terminator. The relevant documentation and specifications specify the current format at least as far back as POSIX.1 2004, and as far as I am aware, no implementation has ever been released that produced any other format, so we can only speculate about why some implementations provide extra space.  Possibilities include, but are not necessarily limited to

- a typo or miscalculation;
- the buffer was (maybe still is) used for more than one thing, and other uses require a couple more bytes;
- an algorithm used by some implementation to format the result benefited from having a couple of extra bytes to work with;
- extra bytes were provided for slop space, to mitigate the effects of hypothetical bugs.

That the same extra bytes are observed today in many implementations may support the multi-use buffer alternative, but that observation is also consistent with any explanation for those bytes appearing in some early implementation, maybe BSD, and being propagated from there to many subsequent ones.  I'm inclined to favor the latter explanation.

Comment: For the record, `inet_ntoa()` first appeared in BSD 4.3.